# What is the alternative for Vaadin 8 ComboBox removeAllItems?

Tags: combobox, vaadin8

I want to remove all the values from combobox in vaadin 8 but removeAllItems is not present in the vaadin 8 api.

What is the alternative for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else works you can always "populate" combobox with an empty list.

```
comboBox.setItems(new ArrayList<YourBean>());
```